# Как использовать action_items и проблема с использованием функций в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Есть два вопроса:

1. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии кнопки выполнялась функция (в моём примере при нажатии Button_1 должна выполнятся функция hl)? В моём случаи результатом является ошибка:

   > AttributeError: 'MainMenu' object has no attribute 'hl'
2. Как сделать что бы при нажатии на left_action_items происходило возвращение на предыдущий Screen (ну и как вообще его использовать, к примеру, что бы при его использовании выполнялась функция или переназначение переменной)? Я пробовал следующий вариант:

`left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda x: app.screen_manager.current = 'Screen_1']]'`

И получил:

> [['arrow-left', lambda x: app.screen_manager.current = 'Screen_1']]
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Пример на котором я экспериментировал:

main.py:

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Window.size = (351, 512)
Builder.load_file('ui.kv')

class MainMenu(Screen):
    def hl(self):
        print('hllo')

class Basic(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Basic, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.title = "KivyMD Examples - Progress Loader"
        self.screen_manager = Factory.ManagerScreens() 


    def build(self):
        return self.screen_manager


Basic().run()
```

ui.kv:

```
<ManagerScreens@ScreenManager>:

    MainMenu:
        id: Screen_1
    Dictionary:
        id: Screen_2

<MainMenu@Screen>:
    name: 'Screen_1'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 30
        spacing: 20
        pos_hint: {'top': 1.6}

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Button_1"
            on_press: root.hl()

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Button_2"
            on_press: app.screen_manager.current = 'Screen_2'    

<Dictionary@Screen>:
    name: 'Screen_2'

    MDToolbar:
        size_hint_y: .08
        title: "Toolbar"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda x: x]]
        pos_hint: {'top':1}

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение первой проблемы моего примера. Оказалось, что нужно просто убрать `@Screen` в `<MainMenu@Screen>:`. Правда я не совсем понял в чём тут штука, но функции заработали и ладно:)